# Using clang-2.9 with Os X 10.5.8 for compiling Z3

Tags: z3, clang++

I would like to use Z3Py and I am trying to install Z3 following the instructions in http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89c1785b7322#README 
I am obtaining the following:

```
dhcp-154:z3-89c1785b7322 mgarcia$ ./configure CXX=clang++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... unsupported
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for int *... no
checking size of int *... 4
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating scripts/config-debug.mk
config.status: creating scripts/config-release.mk
Z3 was configured with success.
Host platform:  osx
Compiler:       clang++
Arithmetic:     internal
Python:         python
Prefix:         /usr
64-bit:         no
```

and when I do the make I get errors as for instance:

```
In file included from ../src/muz_qe/dl_smt_relation.cpp:32:
../src/smt/expr_context_simplifier.h:78:10: error: expected parameter declarator
    void assert(expr* e) { m_solver.assert_expr(e); }

/usr/include/assert.h:85:23: note: instantiated from:
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)

In file included from ../src/muz_qe/dl_smt_relation.cpp:32:
../src/smt/expr_context_simplifier.h:78:10: error: expected ')'
../src/smt/expr_context_simplifier.h:78:10: note: to match this '('
    void assert(expr* e) { m_solver.assert_expr(e); }
```

So I do not know if this is a problem related with the code or I am still missing something. Or, maybe, I am using really older versions.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a similar system here to test, but I believe this is because your system library uses something like

```
#define assert(x) (__builtin_expect...
```

to define the `assert` function. It happens that one of the functions in one of our classes was called `assert` as well and the preprocessor replaces that with the rest of the #define. It seems that this problem is already fixed in the unstable branch of Z3, which you can get from the source code download on [Codeplex](http://z3.codeplex.com), by switching the branch selector from "master" to "unstable" before clicking on Download.

Comment: Thank you, I realize finally my C compiler was not creating executables, and now I am getting some new problems `dhcp-154:build mgarcia$ make
src/shell/datalog_frontend.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fopenmp"
make: *** [shell/datalog_frontend.o] Error 1`  So I guess I need to install something else.

Comment: -fopenmp refers to the OpenMP compiler extensions and library, which many modern compilers support. As far as I know, clang++ does not support it though and the Z3 configuration script should disable it. There is a chance that the script (python scripts/mk_make.py) does not recognize clang++, or that incorrect options were passed to it. You can verify that by checking the output of the script.

Comment: Also, I just found out that older versions of gcc on the mac may not support OpenMP. In case you switched from clang to gcc, could you tell us what `gcc --version` says?

Comment: Yet more information: Note that there was a change to the unstable branch today which added new checks for OpenMP in mk_make. Could you update and retry?

Comment: This is the `gcc -version: i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: no input files` 
Anyway, I will check with the new branch.

Comment: With clang++ and clang or using g++ for the new unstable version I obtain: 
`../src/util/dependency.h:54: error: within this context
make: *** [shell/datalog_frontend.o] Error 1`

Comment: Is there more error information? dependency.h:54 looks rather innocent, so perhaps this is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, there are some more error lines but I had not enough space in Comments.

Comment: `src/shell/datalog_frontend.cpp
../src/util/dependency.h: In constructor ‘dependency_manager<C>::join::join(dependency_manager<C>::dependency*, dependency_manager<C>::dependency*) [with C = ast_manager::expr_dependency_config]’:`

Comment: `../src/util/dependency.h:163:   instantiated from ‘dependency_manager<C>::dependency* dependency_manager<C>::mk_join(dependency_manager<C>::dependency*, dependency_manager<C>::dependency*) [with C = ast_manager::expr_dependency_config]’
../src/ast/ast.h:1829:   instantiated from here
../src/util/dependency.h:37: error: ‘dependency_manager<C>::dependency::dependency(bool) [with C = ast_manager::expr_dependency_config]’ is private
../src/util/dependency.h:54: error: within this context
make: *** [shell/datalog_frontend.o] Error 1`